# Can't download document when calling function getDocument

Tags: docusignapi

Error: Call to a member function read() on string in DocuSign\eSign\ObjectSerializer::deserialize() (line 285 of/vendor/docusign/esign-client/src/ObjectSerializer.php).

I'm calling that function

```
$temp_file = $envelope_api->getDocument($accountID, $document_id, $envelope_id);
```

This is causing the issue

```
$file = fopen($filename, 'w');
while ($chunk = $data->read(200)) {
    fwrite($file, $chunk);
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Would you edit your original question with the code surrounding this call? Also include the arguments you're passing

Comment: @MatthewRoknich I've edited my question

Comment: @MatthewRoknich I've managed to solve the issue. i've downgraded the version to 5.1

Comment: Gah you beat me to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think there's a bug in the PHP SDK (client library) please let us know. 
Version 5.2 was release recently, so it's possible there's some change in behavior compared to version 5.1.

Comment: yes its breaking for me too. Same error as mentioned above.

Comment: please try https://packagist.org/packages/docusign/esign-client version 5.3 and let me know

Comment: there is a Firefox error too when trying to open a PDF instead of save.

Comment: ok, would you mind marking this as answered? the PDF issues is different - you can ask a different question if you need.

Comment: just upvoted the answer.Its not my question actually, so can't accept the answer.